# Transmission Line Theory: Coaxial Cable Per Unit Length Series Resistance Derivation

Tags: electromagnetism

**Brief Background**

A coaxial cable is an example of a transmission line. A transmission line can be analyzed by using a distributed element model in which there are a repeating set of per unit length parameters including

- A series resistance $R'$

  - In a coaxial cable, this is the component representing the losses the electromagnetic wave propagating down the coaxial cable incurs as it encounters a nonideal conductor.
  - There are two nonideal conductors (outer and inner) in a real coaxial cable.
- A shunt conductance $G'$

  - In a coaxial cable, this is due to the nonideal dielectric that causes some current to flow from one conductor to the other.
- A series inductance $L'$

  - In a coaxial cable, there are two parts to series inductance -- an internal inductance and an external inductance.
- A shunt capacitance $C'$

  - In a coaxial cable, the presence of two conductors separated by a dielectric can be modeled as a capacitance.

where the prime notation is there to indicate it is a per unit length parameter.

**Question**

How can I derive the series resistance per unit length $R'$? From electrostatics I know that resistance can be computed from
$$R = \frac{V_{ab}}{I} = \frac{-\int_a^b \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}}{\int_S \sigma \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{S}}$$
where $S$ is the cross-sectional surface through which current $I$ flows. But does this apply in the case of electrodynamics as well? I am aware of how current flows through the bulk of a conductor at DC, but due to induced eddy currents within the conductor at AC, especially at higher frequencies, the current passing through a conductor gets concentrated at the surface.

**Possible Solution**

I have seen people derive this series resistance per unit length $R'$ by considering how much power is lost due to Ohmic losses in the two conductors. It appears that it is assumed that current flows along the surface of these conductors. Consider http://www.dannex.se/theory/4.html starting around Equation 71. It may be that the inspiration for that website's derivations were found on pages 376 and 387 in Cheng's Field and Wave Electromagnetics in sections related to general transmission lines. Can this be done with a more explicit application of Maxwell's equations?

I'd also like to add as an aside that from my attempts to find a solution it appears as though the derivation of the other three parameters is very much more commonly seen.

Comment: The answer is yes. You can assume exponential dependence of the current density, as well as electric and magnetic fields. The resistance can be calculated using the formula you mentioned but it will be different for different paths. The total effective resistance will be obtained by adding all these up using the parallel resistance formula.